# How write in a inputstream

Tags: java, file, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I need to write a file but I must take this element in this way:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Grafica/indice_corrente.txt");
```

Now I need to write in this inputstream the value 10,but I don't know how I can do this. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can't. It's an inputstream. You can only read from it.

Comment: Furthermore, you cannot write to application resources.  If you want to change indice_corrente.txt, create a *new file* with that name, either a temporary file or a file somewhere under the user’s home directory, and write to that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write in a InputStream. If you want to write into a File you need a **FileWriter** or a **BufferedWriter** with an **FileOutputStream**.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to an InputStream.

To write the value 10, you can do something like this:

To write the 10 in ASCII (this means you will write the characters 1 and 0). You can do this.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/Grafica/indice_corrente.txt");
out.print(10);
```

If you want to write the byte 10, use this

```
file = new File("/Grafica/indice_corrente.txt");
os = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(10);
```

Do note however that this will overwrite everything in this text file. If you want to append, and not overwrite, use this:

```
file = new File("/Grafica/indice_corrente.txt");
os = new FileOutputStream(new FileWriter(file, true));
os.write(10);
```